# Quicker alternative to WinAPI PrintWindow()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screenshot

I'm writing a program, which continuously scans some pixels of open windows (which might be in the background) and reacts on a change. I'm currently using the following code:

```
HDC ClientProfile::prepareSurface() {
    UpdateWindow(handle);
    HDC window_dc = GetDC(handle);
    HDC res = CreateCompatibleDC(window_dc);
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect(handle, &r);
    HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(window_dc, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top);
    SelectObject(res, bmp);
    PrintWindow(handle, res, PW_CLIENTONLY);
    DeleteObject(bmp);
    ReleaseDC(handle, window_dc);
    return res;
}
```

I then use GetPixel() on the returned HDC. This works absolutely fine, but when scanning alot of windows simultaneously, it's a little bit too slow for my needs.
I especially noticed that the time PrintWindow() consumes varies based on the application it scans (probably because of the way the message is handled?).
It there a way to speed this up? I tried to use

```
SendMessage(handle,WM_PRINT/WM_PRINTCLIENT, WPARAM(res),PRF_CLIENT);
```

but that didn't work at all (would it even make a difference?).
I couldn't find any other solution to my problem, does any one around here have one maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure its PrintWindow that is a bottleneck? GetPixel might also be time consuming - especially if done on DC that might keep its buffer in video memory.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm only checking single pixels, and only a few per iteration. I checked the program with Intel VTUNE Amplifier and this is what I get. http://s29.postimg.org/gknsnpbgn/performance.png

Comment: What's interesting though: I checked the time the "PrintWindow()" function takes, with windows PerformanceQueryCounter. It returns 1.000 MICROseconds most of the time, but every once in a while (like once per second), it needs around 20.000 microseconds. Why might this be?